# How to deal with mobile browser nav bar?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I'm developing a website. I have a button that I want to be fixed in the right-bottom corner. The problem is, in mobile browsers, it gets covered by the navigation bar:

[image]

The bar sometimes hides while user is scrolling. Can reappear again.

This happens both on Android/Chrome and iOs/Safari.

Is there an elegant way to script the element so it would always be displayed in full and stuck just in the corner of the shown part of the website?

Comment: we need a link and/or code

Comment: You got to place it above the default browser bar

Answer (score 0):

I think the mobile browsers does hides the bar when it is scrolling down and shows it when you scroll up.
Maybe move the location of the button when scrolling up with JS or something.